# How to prove that the following function is continuous?

Tags: measure-theory

Let m be the lebesgue's measure, $[a,b] $ a closed interval and E a mesurable set such that m (E)=p. How can I prove that $f (x)=m ([a,x]∩E)$ is continuous on $[a,b] $

Answer (score 1):

Given a sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} = x$, your task is to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x)$. This would prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Now, notice that each $f(x_n)$ can be written as an integral of an indicator function:
$$ f(x_n) = \int \chi_{[a,x_n] \cap E}.$$

The family of indicator functions $\chi_{[a,x_n] \cap E}$ converges pointwise a.e. to the indicator function $\chi_{[a,x] \cap E}$, and is dominated by the indicator function $\chi_E$, which is integrable since $m(E) < \infty$.

Hence, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \int \chi_{[a,x] \cap E} = f(x),$$
as required.